# Excel - How to selectively run Hyperlink event VBA code depending on what worksheet it is jumping to?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have hyperlinks in a worksheet that jump to cells using a named range in other worksheets.  The below working code switches worksheets (based on hyperlink) and puts the target cell in the upper left hand corner when I click on the hyperlink. This works perfectly.

However, on one particular hyperlink I want it to only switch to the worksheet but I don't want to run the below code to have it placed in the Upper left.  I just want to switch worksheets and leave positioning alone.

Since the below code is an event when any hyperlink is clicked I would like to check for the particular target worksheet and not run the below code.

Is there a way (if...then?) to detect the worksheet I'm switching to and not execute the below code?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```

Psuedo Code - I'm looking for the VBA code in bold.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    **If (name in hyperlink) = "my target sheet" Then exit sub**

    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple. :)  I know nothing of VBA but BigBen gave me some hints.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Name = "<target sheetname>" Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```